# How to manually turn on the screen during a call, while proximity sensor thinks I'm too close?

Tags: proximity-sensor

Something's wrong with my phone's proximity sensor and it sometimes thinks I'm too close to my phone even when I'm not.

**Unlike the five related questions I found ([1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/133160/screen-turns-off-during-call-due-to-problem-with-proximity-sensor-xperia-z3-co), [2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28294/disable-automatic-screen-turn-off-during-call), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982571/disable-proximity-sensor-during-call), [4](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35194/unable-to-turn-on-screen-during-calls), [5](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/103483/disable-screen-turn-off-during-phone-call?rq=1)!),** including one with the same model of phone, I don't want the screen to always be on, and I don't want the proximity sensor to be completely disabled (it sometimes gets it right). I want the screen to be off as normal during a call, and I'd like the proxmity sensor to continue turning the screen on if it thinks I'm "far", but I'd like to also be able to turn the screen on manually when I press a button (I'm not fussy about what button) and overrule the sensor during a call.

I thought this used to be standard... I'm sure my first few Android phones could turn the screen on manually during a call by pressing a button, but no button I've tried does anything (one exception - in Skype and only Skype, pressing the power button turns the screen on for half a second, then it turns back off again).

Sony Xperia Z3 Compact, Android 5.1.1, not rooted (and ideally I'd keep it that way).

---

I've tried using MacroDroid, and while it can respond during a call, it can't turn the screen on. For example, if I create a macro to enable Bluetooth and turn on the screen if I shake the phone during a call, then I shake the phone during a call, the screen stays off but bluetooth does turn on.

There's no option "Turn off screen during calls" in my phone's Call Settings, nor do I have a "Turn on proximity sensor" option under Additional Settings. I do have an option to make the power button hang up during a call, but not to turn the screen on.

---

To re-iterate, unlike the existing questions, I don't want to stop the screen turning off or disable the proximity sensor completely, I just want to be able to manually override it and manually turn the screen on during a call, using a button.

Comment: I have the exact same issue on same phone model, would love a solution to this. I've tried numerous apps which promise to override the proximity sensor behaviour but with no joy.